# How does Buefy datepicker output 'yyyy-MM-dd' string?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, buefy

I have a date picker in my Buefy form in my Vue application that is suppose to populates a table from an api call. I populate the api call with the Buefy form. 
the api call needs the format 'yyyy-MM-dd' but i receive a totally different format from buefy `v-model="startdate"`.

I am passing the startdate into the api call as of `${this.startdate}`.
I need it to be a string in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd'.
example date string: '2019-04-23'

how do I achieve this? is it possible with the date-parser property of buefy datepicker ? if so what would the function be?

so far I have `:date-parser="dateParser"` in the b-datepicker tag

and in the methods i have

```
dateParser(date) {
      new Date.parse(date);
    }
```

whats next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as of Walter's reply, I used the logic below to retrieve my answer:

```
let myDate = new Date(Date.parse(this.startdate));
      let realDate =
        myDate.getFullYear() +
        "-" +
        ("0" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
        "-" +
        ("0" + myDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker accepts only Date JavaScript object. You have to format the date object to string in the server pattern before to call API.
Formatter and Parser props are only for internal and display use.

Comment: thank you for the reply, figured it wasnt for me that property.